# Type "Hello, World!"

Tags: code-golf, hello-world

Write a program which generates keyboard events which type `Hello, World!`.

It doesn't have to be platform-independent.

It can't leave any keys pressed.  For example, in Java, `Robot.KeyPress('H');` will leave `H` pressed, so you must release it with `Robot.KeyRelease('H');`

You may assume that the caps lock is off when your program is run.  Capital letters can be typed either by holding shift and pressing the letter, or by toggling caps lock.  For the `!`, you'll probably have to use the shift method.

Shortest code wins.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## C (Linux), 186 bytes

```
#include<sys/ioctl.h>
#include<fcntl.h>
#include<stdio.h>
main(){char*s="Hello, World!",d[99],*c;fscanf(popen("tty","r"),"%s",d);int D=open(d,O_RDWR);for(c=s;*c;c++)ioctl(D,TIOCSTI,c);}
```

After applying ugoren's suggestions:

### 111 bytes

```
main(D){char*c,d[99];fscanf(popen("tty","r"),"%s",d);D=open(d,2);for(c="Hello, World!";*c;)ioctl(D,21522,c++);}
```

Comment: You can shorten some. Remove `s` (just initialize `for(c="H..`), increment `c` in the `ioctl`, `main(D)` to save `int`. Maybe also remove some includes (even hard-code `O_RDWR` and `TIOCSTI`).

Comment: @ugoren Thanks, I'll try them :)

Comment: This one is not the shortest. Why is this the accepted answer? (I think it is a nice answer, but I just want to learn how the site works.)

Comment: @11684 The author of the shortest answer asked me not to count it, so I accepted the shortest non-trivial answer instead.

Comment: No need to call `tty` it only works if stdin is a tty, in which case, `0` is already an open terminal fd.

Answer (score 18):

## AppleScript, 50 bytes

```
tell app"System Events"to keystroke"Hello, World!"
```

Thanks to marinus for the suggestion.

Comment: Huh.  Looks like you chose the right language for the right job.

Comment: You can shorten it to `tell app"System Events"to keystroke"Hello, World!"`.

Comment: Damnit, I thought of this independently... +1!

Answer (score 13):

## Autohotkey, 20 bytes

```
send Hello, World{!}
```

***Please don't count this one.*** I don't want to cheat out people who have actually done this with a language not meant for sending keystrokes. This answer is just for completion :P

Answer (score 3):

## C in Windows 7, 201 bytes

```
#include<windows.h>
#include<winable.h>
#define S SendInput(1,&k,28);
int k[7]={1};main(i){char*s="^HELLO, ^WORLD^1";for(i=0;i<16;i++){k[2]=0;if(s[i]>90){k[1]=16;S i++;}k[1]=s[i];S k[2]=2;S k[1]=16;S}}
```

Program result:

```
C:\My\Directory>type.exe

C:\My\Directory>Hello, World!
```

Answer (score 3):

## Emacs Lisp, 34 bytes

`(execute-kbd-macro"Hello, World!")`

Answer (score 1):

## Ducky Script for USB Rubber Ducky, 22 bytes

```
String "Hello, World!"
```

Answer (score 1):

## AutoIt3, 21 bytes

```
Send("Hello, World!")
```

Comment: missing comma! It's actually 21 chars

Comment: Where is a comma supposed to be? Edit, never mind, lol.

Answer (score 1):

## Tcl, 46 bytes

```
package r Expect;spawn bash;send Hello,\ World
```

## Expect, 29 bytes

```
spawn bash;send Hello,\ World
```

Comment: Tried to do the Tk version, but failed: file with some stuff https://pastebin.ca/3897417

Answer (score 1):

## VBScript, 54 bytes

```
createobject("wscript.shell").sendkeys "Hello, World!"
```

Answer (score 0):

## InstantEXE 3.0, 20 bytes

```
Keys "Hello, World!"
```

Answer (score 0):

## PowerShell, 55 bytes

```
(New-Object -c wscript.shell).sendkeys('Hello, World!')
```

Answer (score 0):

### Python 3,67 bytes

```
from pynput.keyboard import*
s=Controller()
s.type("Hello, World!")
```

*No module named pynput on tio*

Comment: `Controller().type("Hello, World!")` ?